# SQL Indexing Strategy on Link Tables

Tags: sql, indexing

I often find myself creating 'link tables'.  For example, the following table maps a user record to an event record.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLog](
    [EventId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL
)
```

For the purposes of this question, please assume the combination of EventId plus UserId is unique and that the database in question is a MS SQL Server 2008 installation.

The problem I have is that I am never sure as to how these tables should be indexed.  For example, I might want to list all users for a particular event, or I might want to list all events for a particular user or, perhaps, retrieve a particular EventId/UserId record.  Indexing options I have considered include:

1. Creating a compound primary key on EventId and UserId (but I
   understand the index won't be useful when accessing by UserId on its
   own).
2. Creating a compound primary key on EventId and UserId and a adding a
   supplemental index on UserId.
3. Creating a primary key on EventId and a supplemental index on
   UserId.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Number 3 would limit you to 1 user per event.

Comment: @Neilski regarding (1) and (2) Some DBMS can use an index even if the column in question is indexed as the second column (for example, Oracle can do that) - that is of course less performant than using the first index column.

Comment: I would have 2 indexes (primary and unique), on `(eventid,userid)` and on `(userid,eventid)` and possibly others, if you have queries that involve the `time` and/or the `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on several aspects.

1. It depends on the DBMS you are going to use. Some prefer single-column indexes (like Postgresql), some can take more advantage of multi-column indexes (like Oracle). Some can answer a query completely from a covering index (like sqlite), others cannot and eventually have to read the pages of the actual table (again, like postgres).
2. It depends on the queries you want to answer. For example, do you navigate in both directions, i.e., do you join on both of your Id columns?
3. It depends on your space and processing time requirements for data modification, too. Keep in mind that indexes are often bigger than the actual table that they index, and that updating indexes is often more expensive that just updating the underlying table.

EDIT:

When your conceptual model has a many-to-many relationship R between two entities E1 and E2, i.e., the logical semantics of R is either "related" or "not-related", than I would always declare that combined primary key for R. That will create a unique index. The primary motivation is, however, data consistency, not query optimization, i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLog](
    [EventId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY([EventId],[UserId])
```

)

Comment: Thank you Fabian.  To answer your questions, this is on a MS SQL Server 2008 installation.  Typically, I need to do three things: 1) List all Users for a particular EventId, 2) List all Events for a particular UserId and 3) Lookup an EvenLog record by EventId and UserId

Comment: AFAIK, MS SQL Server cannot do index skip scans, so if you have PRIMARY KEY([EventId],[UserId]), that index could be not be efficiently used to query by UserId (you might want to verify that with your execution plans). However, as @kapelchik wrote, I would not create any indexes (apart from those unique indexes that enforce data consistency) before you have evidence that they are actually needed, so you should check your execution plans.

Comment: Execution Plans are not something I have a lot of experience with so I will do some research - thanks for your help.

Comment: IMO, understanding plans is very educational in order to understand how a DBMS processes queries and when (and how) it can take advantage of indexes. Sometimes it is surprising that a lot of indexes are actually never used for, various reasons. For a quick check, however, simply monitoring the runtime of your query will be a good first estimate, too.

Answer (score 2):

The indices are designed to solve performance problems. If you don't yet have such problem and cannot exactly know where you'll face troubles then you shouldn't create indexes. The indices are quite expensive. Because it not only takes up disk space but also causes the overhead of writing or modifying data. So you have to be clear understand what the specific performance problem you decide by creating an index. So you can appreciate the need to create it.

Comment: Thank you Kapelchik. I was under the impression, perhaps mistakenly,  that you 'should' always add indexes to fields that you knew would be used for retrieval/lookup.  In the above example, there may be 100,000 rows in the EventLog table and I wanted to try and ensure 'good' performance from the get-go.  Are you saying that this approach is incorrect and I should only consider adding the indexes if lack of performance demands?